# How do I check to see if my string contains spaces using preg_match?

Tags: php, regex

i use this code in php to detect if the string contains characters other than a-z,A-Z,0-9. I want to check if the string contains any spaces. What should I add to the pattern?

```
if (preg_match ('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/i', $getmail)) {
    // The string contains characters other than a-z and A-Z and 0-9
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to add space to your current pattern, you actually need to input space in your pattern:

```
/[^a-z0-9 ]/i
         ^
      Notice the space there
```

- [Useful Resources](http://gnosis.cx/publish/programming/regular_expressions.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can try this

```
/[^a-z0-9\s]/i
```

As you used the `i` modifier no need for `A-Z`. The `\s` part will mean spaces, but also tabs or any white space.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (preg_match('/[^a-z0-9 ]/i', $getmail)) // The string contains characters other than a-z (case insensitive), 0-9 and space
```

Note I removed A-Z from the character class too as you have case insensitivity turned on.